# AWS s3, lambda. How do you download image from tmp that has a prefix?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, file, amazon-s3

I am currently learning AWS, mostly s3 and lambda services. The idea is to save an image in one bucket, resize it and move to another bucket. I have searched for dozen tutorials and finally made it work. However, I have not found(or don`t know how to search) for an example of how to deal with images with prefixes.

This is the code I am using:

```
def resize_image(image_path, resized_path):
    with Image.open(image_path) as image:
        # image.thumbnail((128, 128))
        image.save(resized_path,optimize=True,quality=20)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    for record in event['Records']:
        bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        key = record['s3']['object']['key'] 
        
        download_path = '/tmp/'+key
        upload_path = '/tmp/resized-{}'.format(key)

        s3_client.download_file(bucket, key, download_path)
        resize_image(download_path, upload_path)
        s3_client.upload_file(upload_path, 'bucket2', key)
```

It all works perfectly if my image is named just 'test.jpg'. However, my real images are stored in multiple directories seperated by year, month, day. And it looks something like this: '2020/06/10/test.jpg'. But even if I upload an image with one prefix, for example: 'test/test.jpg' and try to use my resize function, I get this error:

```
[ERROR] FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/test/test.jpg.fDAe2cFd'
```

Obviously this is not correct, because tmp folder does not have folders itself. But how do I get the image then? I tried using just the image name to check if the file exists like this:

```
    download_path = '/tmp/'+os.path.basename(key)
    upload_path = '/tmp/resized-{}'.format(os.path.basename(key))
```

Obviously the image does not exist:

```
[ERROR] UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file '/tmp/test.jpg'
```

So what is the correct solution to this problem? I am fairly new to this whole AWS thing and getting stuck constantly... Its starting to get really annoying and im losing hope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for `upload_file()` is:

```
upload_file(Filename, Bucket, Key)
```

Therefore, this line in your code:

```
s3_client.upload_file(upload_path, 'bucket2', key)
```

should be:

```
s3_client.upload_file(download_path, 'bucket2', upload_path)
```

So, I'm surprised that your code is working at all, even with no directories.

The reason that your code is failing with multiple directories is due to these lines:

```py
download_path = '/tmp/'+key

s3_client.download_file(bucket, key, download_path)
```

If the key is `foo/bar` then it will attempt to download a file to `/tmp/foo/bar`. However, the `/tmp/foo` directory does not exist. Unlike Amazon S3, operating systems normally want a directory to exist *before* writing a file to that location.

I notice that your code is based on [Tutorial: Using an Amazon S3 trigger to create thumbnail images - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-tutorial.html). In that sample code, you'll notice that it contains this line:

```
tmpkey = key.replace('/', '')
```

This removes subdirectories from the path, thus avoiding the problem.